# How to change base skin url based on browser nginx

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, nginx, base-url

I'm running an https magento site on a nginx server.  I'd like to serve my static content from a cdn (Amazon Cloudfront).

I can do this easily by changing the media/css/js urls from

www.mysite.com/xxx 
to 
cdn.mysite.com/xxx

however older browsers & operating systems (XP for example) don't support the SNI that makes this possible.

So, my question is:

How can I set my media/css/js base urls to be (www.mysite.com/xxx) when I detect that a user is running XP (for example), but leave them as cdn.mysite.com/xxx by default

I'd prefer not to have to set up multiple stores, just to be able to change these variables without the user knowing anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is going to be a nice clean solution here without using multiple stores to be honest but an option, not a great option is to rewrite `Mage_Core_Model_Store` and alter what is returned by the `getBaseUrl()` method according to browser?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, do you think the 'clean' way to solve this would be to use multiple stores?

Comment: I just don't like to rewrite such a fundamental class as `Mage_Core_Model_Store` so for me, if it can be achieved by not doing this then that is going to be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

We implemented a server side change of skin, template & layout using `controller_action_predispatch` event:

```
$urlModel = Mage::getModel('core/url');
/* @var $urlModel Mage_Core_Model_Url */
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
/* @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
$code  = $store->getCode();
if (1 == 1) {
    $config = Mage::getConfig();
    /* @var $config Mage_Core_Model_Config */
    $config->setNode('stores/'.$code.'/design/theme/template', 'iphonetheme', true);
    $config->setNode('stores/'.$code.'/design/theme/skin', 'iphonetheme', true);
    $config->setNode('stores/'.$code.'/design/theme/layout', 'iphonetheme', true);
}
```